# How to write a simple sql procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am working on sql server database. I have 2 tables with `1 to many` association in my db. First is **Parent** table and second is **Child** table. **Parent** table has a column *ChildCount* which will update whenever the child entries for this parent is added or deleted.

So for this i decided to write a stored procedure and a DML trigger which will execute on INSERT and DELETE operations on **Child** table. I am totally new in database. What i tried yet is :

*First i am trying to create a procedure ( which i will execute from the trigger )*

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ChildCount]
    @parentId int
AS
    //here first i have to extract the total child for the given parentId and 
    //than in the next update statement i will update the count.

    UPDATE Parent
    SET ChildCount = //above total child value
    WHERE Id = parentId
RETURN 0
```

Here i don't understand how to extract a total child and save it in a variable and than use that variable in the update statement ??

And please after guiding me on this CREATE PROCEDURE, suggest me on what i am doing this is correct, good and efficient approach or there is other better approach for doing this ??

Comment: hey , why down vote ? I told i am totally new in database

Comment: Are you going to execute this code from somewhere other than the trigger? If not, you might as well just put the code into the trigger.

Comment: No column is `ChildCount` with total child i means to say all childs for a single parent entry

Comment: Why do you need to store the count? You could calculate it in the queries where needed instead.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson Yes that's the another approach but isn't slow my app to query each time whenever we want total child ?

Comment: Depends on your situation but if you have an index on your foreign key in the child table I think you should do alright. My advice is that you should not do the trigger untill you have tested the alternative and seen that it does not perform good enough.

Comment: BTW, the trigger code to call the SP you have will not be trivial or optimized. The trigger is executed once per batch, not once per row. So the inserted and deleted pseudo tables has to be processed one row at a time in the trigger if you are to call the SP from the trigger.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson than what should be the better approach for doing this ?

Comment: Don't use the trigger at all :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ChildCount]
        @parentId int
    AS

    Begin
    Declare @i as int;

    Select @i=count(child) from childtable where parentid=@parentId 

        UPDATE Parent
        SET ChildCount =@i
        WHERE Id = @parentId
    End
```

Comment: thanks for answer, can you please tell me is my approach for doing this is efficient or i can do this with some other better approach ?

Comment: better approach to write trigger...for insert and delete  in child table for corresponding parent id...it will automatically increment or decrement the the count of child in parent table when ever insertion or deletion is dont in child table.....

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this with a trigger it could be something like this:

```
create trigger dbo.tr_Child on dbo.Child for insert, update, delete
as

update dbo.Parent
set ChildCount = (select count(*) from dbo.Child where Child.ParentID = T.ParentID)
from 
  (
  select ParentID from inserted union 
  select ParentID from deleted
  ) as T
where Parent.ParentID = T.ParentID;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/251b7/12)

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider using computed columns instead of triggers. Just create a UDF that will return the number of children for a given parent and create a computed column out of it.

Here is how it might look like

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetChildCount(@ParentID int)
RETURNS int
BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Child WHERE ParentID = @ParentID)
END


ALTER TABLE Parent
    ChildCount as dbo.GetChildCount(ParentID)
```

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2011/11/28/a-computed-column-defined-with-a-user-defined-function-might-impact-query-performance.aspx) is a link with more details.